# handling errors gracefully if proxy server is not available

Tags: f#

I've a specified proxy within my code and would like to handle error gracefully if proxy server is not running. I'm using Charles proxy.

```
let request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(Uri url)
request.Proxy <- WebProxy("localhost", 8888)
request.Method <- "GET"

async {
    try
        use! response = request.AsyncGetResponse()
        use stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        use reader = new StreamReader(stream)
        return Ok (reader.ReadToEnd())
    with :? WebException as e -> 
        use response = e.Response :?> HttpWebResponse
        use stream = response.GetResponseStream() // error
        use streamReader = new StreamReader(stream)
        use memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(streamReader.ReadToEnd()))
        // use memoryStream
        return Error {Status = response.StatusCode}
}
```

Following line is throwing an error if proxy server is not available. How can I handle this situation gracefully?

```
use stream = response.GetResponseStream()
```

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: move it out of the with block, and handle the NullReferenceException. You're only handling WebException. Why do you have it in the try block anyway?

Comment: not sure if got your comment right

Comment: yeah, i meant why do u have it in the `with` block, but i cant edit comments.

Comment: this api returns descriptive error messages in case like 401, 404 etc. that I need to display to client, so I've the http call within try with blocks

Comment: you can branch in the `with` block, add a handler for `NullReferenceException`, alternatively use a `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

[WebException.Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response(v=vs.110).aspx) states that

> **If a response is available** from the Internet resource, a WebResponse
>   instance that contains the error response from an Internet resource;
>   **otherwise, null**.

Which means that your line

```
use response = e.Response :?> HttpWebResponse
```

results in `null` because no response is available. Which makes sense since the proxy which is supposed to send the request is not available.

you can use the function `isNull` to check for the null value e.g.

```
let request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(Uri url)
request.Proxy <- WebProxy("localhost", 8888)
request.Method <- "GET"

async {
    try
        use! response = request.AsyncGetResponse()
        use stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        use reader = new StreamReader(stream)
        return Ok (reader.ReadToEnd())
    with :? WebException as e -> 
        use response = e.Response :?> HttpWebResponse
        if isNull(response) then
            return Error {Status = response.StatusCode}
        else
            use stream = response.GetResponseStream() // error
            use streamReader = new StreamReader(stream)
            use memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(streamReader.ReadToEnd()))
            // use memoryStream
            return Error {Status = response.StatusCode}
}
```

Comment: I think `use response = e.Response :?> HttpWebResponse` should be after, it's failing at coercing. Another side effect is that since `.e.Response` is null so there's no `StatusCode` and I'm actually using `public enum HttpStatusCode` as a type for this field. Now this scenario is essentially a representation of being offline, JavaScript API returned 0 (zero) as statusCode but not sure how can I represent 0 or offline in given http status codes within f#